# Is Possible to Set Cookie on Request Headers on Fetch (React Js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I want to push a Cookie on header, that's a code :

```js
async ({ username, password, captcha, idCaptcha }, thunkAPI) => {
    console.log(idCaptcha)
    const response = await fetch(`${API_ACCOUNT}/auth/login`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        // 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
        Cookie: 'JSESSIONID=' + idCaptcha,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        // 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      // body: new URLSearchParams({
      //   username: username,
      //   password: password,
      //   grant_type: 'password',
      //   captcha: captcha,
      // }),
      body: `username=${username}&password=${password}&grant_type=password&captcha=${captcha}`,
    })
   })
```

but on the develeoper tools , i can't find a key Cookie
[image]

Anyone can explain to me , what wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set Cookie

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();
cookies.set('myCat', 'Pacman', { path: '/' }); // path is optional
```